# express js: is there a way to map all the rest of url as one parameter?

Tags: node.js, express

The code segment is:

```
  app.get('/api/photo/:S3ObjectKey', photo.get);
```

And `photo.get()`:

```
  const S3ObjectKey = req.params.S3ObjectKey;
  if (!S3ObjectKey) {
    console.log("No S3ObjectKey specified");
  }
  console.log("S3ObjectKey: ", S3ObjectKey);

  const canShow = true;
  if (canShow) {
    const bucket_name = process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME;
    const data = await S3.getFile(bucket_name, S3ObjectKey);
    data.Body.pipe(res);
  }
```

Is there a way to map all the rest of url as one parameter, such that:

a GET request to `https://mylovelydomain/api/photo/bucketMyPhoto/2020/07/12/home/table.jpeg` would hit the api endpoint and `S3ObjectKey` has the value `bucketMyPhoto/2020/07/12/home/table.jpeg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express uses [path-to-regex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp#custom-matching-parameters):

> Custom Matching Parameters
> Parameters can have a custom regexp, which overrides the default match ([^/]+).

On your routing path you can use `*` to get everything overwriting that default match (note that this code also reatcs to empty requests):

```js
    app.get("/api/photos/:S3ObjectKey(*)", /*...*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per express documentation, route path supports regular expression, so should be able to do it. Quoting the example from the documentation.

[image]